# How to modify only the background colour of a colourscheme in neovim using lua

Tags: neovim, vimscript-lua

I am slowly switching my neovim configurations to Lua. I am currently using the colour scheme
https://github.com/nightsense/snow. It sets the background colour to a light-grey, while I want it to be a darker tone of grey. Previously, when using vimL, I used to use the following snippet to change the background colour (to match my terminal colour).

```
set termguicolors
try
    colorscheme snow
    set background=dark
    hi Normal ctermbg=232 guibg=#0a0a0a
catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E185/
    colorscheme default
endtry
```

I am trying to achieve the same in my Neovim Lua based configuration. I tried the following piece of code to do so.

```
vim.cmd('set background=dark')
vim.cmd('colorscheme snow')
vim.cmd('hi Normal guibg=#0a0a0a')
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2):

This was how I sorted out my problem in the end

```
vim.api.nvim_command([[
    augroup ChangeBackgroudColour
        autocmd colorscheme * :hi normal guibg=#0a0a0a
    augroup END
]])
vim.o.termguicolors = true
vim.cmd [[silent! colorscheme snow]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I see no particular problem about Lua syntax. Perhaps, you simply forgot to set termguicolors or your console does not support 24-bit color at all. Anyway, the following seems to work just fine:

```lua
    vim.o.termguicolors = true
    vim.o.background = "dark"
    vim.cmd [[
        silent! colorscheme snow
        hi Normal guibg=#0a0a0a
    ]]
```

But note that you have to "patch" background after any colorscheme change, so usually one does make use of an auto-command.

Comment: The above code did not work for me. However, your comment about autocommand gave me a hint to find a solution. I have written down the way I solved this issue as a separate answer.